# Survey App Using Nested Models, Partials, & Rails Form Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, formbuilder

I extracted this code from the following engine:

**Link to Demo:**
https://rapidfire.herokuapp.com/rapidfire/question_groups/1110/answer_groups/new

**Link to Code:**
https://github.com/code-mancers/rapidfire/blob/master/app/services/rapidfire/answer_group_builder.rb

I trying to modify it so that I can create custom answer types, called "kind"(s) (see schema). One kind called "indicator" (see _indicator.html.erb), has multiple columns.

My models are setup as follows:

```
Survey
  has_many :question_groups
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_groups
end

QuestionGroup
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

AnswerGroup
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

Answer
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer_group, inverse_of: :answers
end
```

**Question 1: What does this line do?** (see build_answer_group method)

```
@answers = question_group.questions.collect do |question|
```

In the console,

```
@answers = [#<Answer id: nil, answer_group_id: nil, question_id: 1034,
answer_text: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Answer id: nil,
answer_group_id: nil, question_id: 1035, answer_text: nil, created_at: nil,
updated_at: nil>]
```

question_ids 1034 and 1035 refer to the last items in the array produced by

```
question_group.questions
```

Instead, I need @answers to be the Answer class equivalent of all questions.
Why is it returning only two items?

**Question 2:**
For the indicator partial, I need to display the name of the Question Group and the names of each subitem, e.g. "Questions", and five additional columns with unique html names and ids. So, if I had two question groups of kind "indicator", I need to produce something like:

```
QuestionGroup1.name
id = answer_group_1034_answer_text name = answer_group[1034][answer_text]
id = answer_group_1035_answer_text name = answer_group[1035][answer_text]
etc...

QuestionGroup2.name
id = answer_group_1036_answer_text name = answer_group[1036][answer_text]
id = answer_group_1037_answer_text name = answer_group[1037][answer_text]
```

Currently, it is producing:

```
For QuestionGroup1:

<textarea rows="5" name="answer_group[1034][answer_text]"
id="answer_group_1034_answer_text"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" name="answer_group[1034][answer_text]"
id="answer_group_1034_answer_text"></textarea>


For QuestionGroup2:

<textarea rows="5" name="answer_group[1035][answer_text]"
id="answer_group_1034_answer_text"></textarea>
<textarea rows="5" name="answer_group[1035][answer_text]"
id="answer_group_1034_answer_text"></textarea>
```

**Goal: Assign a unique id and name for each row within a question group for the indicator partial**

views/answer_groups/_fidelitychecklist.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@survey, @answer_group_builder]) do |f| %>
   <% @answer_group_builder.answers.each do |answer| %>
     <%= f.fields_for("#{answer.question.id}", answer) do |answer_form| %>
       <%= render_answer_form_helper(answer, answer_form) %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

services/answer_group_builder.rb

```
class AnswerGroupBuilder < BaseService
  attr_accessor :user, :survey, :questions, :answers, :params

  def initialize(params = {})
   super(params)
   build_answer_group
  end

  def to_model
   @answer_group
  end

  ...

  private
  def build_answer_group
    @answer_group = AnswerGroup.new(user: user, survey: survey)

    @survey.question_groups.each do |question_group|
      @answers = question_group.questions.collect do |question|
        @answer_group.answers.build(question_id: question.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

AnswerGroupsController

```
before_filter :find_survey!

def new
  @answer_group_builder = AnswerGroupBuilder.new(answer_group_params)
end

def create
  @answer_group_builder = AnswerGroupBuilder.new(answer_group_params)

  if @answer_group_builder.save
    redirect_to surveys_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
def find_survey!
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
end

def answer_group_params
  answer_params = { params: params[:answer_group] }
  answer_params.merge(user: current_user, survey: @survey)
end
```

module ApplicationHelper

```
def render_answer_form_helper(answer, form)
  partial = Question.where(id: answer.question_id).last.question_group.kind.to_s
  questiongroup = Question.find(answer.question_id).question_group
  render partial: "/answers/#{partial}", locals: {f: form, answer: answer, questiongroup: questiongroup }
end
```

views/answers/_indicator.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "answers/errors", locals: {answer: answer} %>

<fieldset>
  <table class="indicator">
    <thead>
      <th class="first head-row">Indicators</th>
      <th class="head-row">Presence</th>
      <th class="head-row">Rating</th>
      <th class="head-row">Element(s) Implemented Well</th>
      <th class="head-row">Element(s) Requiring Further Support</th>
      <th class="head-row">Comments/Action Steps</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td colspan="6" class="indicator-title"><%= questiongroup.name %></td></tr>

      <% questiongroup.questions.each do |question| %>

      <tr>
        <td class="first row">
            <%= question.question_text %>
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            <%= f.select :answer_text, options_for_select([["N/O", "n/o"], ["N", "n"]]) %>
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            <%= f.select :answer_text, options_for_select([["1", "1"], ["2", "2"], ["3", "3"]]) %>
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            <%= f.text_area :answer_text, rows: 5 %>
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            <%= f.text_area :answer_text, rows: 5 %>
        </td>
        <td class="row">
            <%= f.text_area :answer_text, rows: 5 %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "surveys", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",            limit: 255
end

create_table "question_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",       limit: 255
  t.integer  "position",   limit: 4
  t.integer  "survey_id",  limit: 4
  t.text     "kind",       limit: 65535
end

create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "question_text",     limit: 255
  t.integer  "position",          limit: 4
  t.integer  "question_group_id", limit: 4
end

create_table "answer_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "survey_id",  limit: 4
end

create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "answer_group_id", limit: 4
  t.integer  "question_id",     limit: 4
  t.text     "answer_text",     limit: 65535
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :surveys do
  resources :answer_groups, only: [:new, :create] do
  end
end
```

Comment: From your question 1: `@answers = question_group.questions.collect do |question|`, this should return Question objects, but you said you received `[Answer,  Answer]`. Is there a typo in your question 1?

Comment: No, it's actually returning [Answer, Answer].  If I change "collect" to "each" it will return a Question object, which is the root of my confusion.  Why is it returning an Answer object in the first place?

Comment: @answers becomes the nested array for the form builder object

Comment: The only way `@answers = question_group.questions.collect do |question|` would return [Answer, Answer] is that at the very end of the do-end block, `question.answer` was  the last executed code in the loop, you could test that if you add 'HelloWorld' at the end of that do-end block, you will instead receive  ['HelloWorld', 'HelloWorld'] and not [Answer, Answer]. So if you want to collect the question instead of the answer, add `question` at the end of the do-end block.

Comment: `#<AnswerGroupBuilder:0x007f8301564c90 @params=nil, @user=nil, @survey=#<Survey id: 11, name: "Fidelity Checklist", created_at: "2015-08-06 22:34:22", updated_at: "2015-08-10 19:43:19",  @answer_group=#<AnswerGroup id: nil, survey_id: 11, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @answers=[#<Answer id: nil, answer_group_id: nil, question_id: 1034, answer_text: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Answer id: nil, answer_group_id: nil, question_id: 1035, answer_text: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>], @errors=#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f83058d1118 ..., >>`

Comment: I'm sorry I think I spoke too soon.  What do you mean by `[Answer, Answer]`?  The code above is what it's returning.  I actually need the form buider object to continue to do what it's doing, e.g. returning `@answers` as a nested array of answers for each question, in order to build the `AnswerForm`.  I don't know why it's only returning two items though.

Comment: You could retrieve all answers whose question_group.kind is the same by (you can replace the wrapper collect block with this, but inside of the loop remains the same): Question.includes(:question_group).where( question_groups: {kind: question_group.kind} ).each do |question| ... end

Comment: Thanks for you help! I'm afraid we've produced a different way of arriving at the same problem.  Now `@answer_group_builder.answers` produces an array of 2 Questions. After adjusting the code as appropriate for the helper method and views, I now get a form with two question groups, and each row within the question group has the same id.  Instead, I need each row to have a different id.